# C# Console application on Linux and Environment variable

Tags: c#, linux, environment-variables, rhel8

I have a C# console application that I compiled for Linux. The application needs to access environment variables. I tried setting it up using `EXPORT var1=value1` or by setting it in `/etc/environment`. I see the environment variable is set correctly when I do `printenv`, but when my application runs it can't access the variable.

Can someone suggest how to make my application access environment variables? I am running it on RHEL 8 and in my application, I am accessing environment variable using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`

Here is a code to demonstrate it:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEBREW_PREFIX");

        Console.WriteLine($"In worker process: {env}");
        _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

Here is a partial output from `printenv` that shows environment variable called `HOMEBREW_PREFIX` set correctly.

```
HOMEBREW_PREFIX=/opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_CELLAR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar
```

Here is screenshot at the breakpoint and my watch window:

[image]

This happens on both my mac and my RHEL box. `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` return `null` and can't access environment variables.

There is yet [another question that seems to be doing similar things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75225452), but I am trying to access an environment variable which already exists, while the other one is trying to set it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your question is a bit opaque. Can you post code demonstrating what you are attempting to do?

Comment: @JoelR.Hall, I added a code to demonstrate the issue

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75229470/10024425 - the post was written for Windows, but you may find some code that may be useful.

Comment: Read the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51934515/how-do-environment-variables-get-picked-up-with-net-core

Comment: I think the most important bit of information is missing in your question - how do you launch the application?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, I came across that thread and tried to get all environment variables, when dotnet process launches, it only spits only few environment variables while parent process (shell) has access to lot many environment variables

Comment: @fredrik, I am currently launching my application either through `dotnet APPLCIATON.dll` or by directly executing binary `./APPLICATION`

Comment: So if you go outside that IDE you're uin and launch the application it doesn't have any environment variables set? How is the initialization of the application set up?

Comment: Just in case that's Jetbrain Rider you're using, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51934515/how-do-environment-variables-get-picked-up-with-net-core and especially the OPs own answer

Comment: @AndyJohnson It's not about what the parent process has access to, but what that process actually owns.

Comment: This is one of those circumstances where it might be worthwhile to simply take a different approach to the problem. Instead of using EVs, perhaps it would make more sense to have a json "config" file containing the EV values that could be read during initialization of the app. There is a reason why config files are so widely used. If you really do need to access real EV values, you could always create a script to redirect those values to a text file and pass the filepath to the app on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

In looking through the online docs for Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable, I noticed the following under the **Remarks** heading:

> The GetEnvironmentVariable(String) method retrieves an environment
> variable from the environment block of the current process only. It is
> equivalent to calling the GetEnvironmentVariable(String,
> EnvironmentVariableTarget) method with a target value of
> EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process.
>
> To retrieve all environment variables along with their values, call
> the **GetEnvironmentVariables** method.

Try switching to that method to see if that solves your problem.

Comment: I tried getting variables using `GetEnvironmentVariables` and just dump it on shell. It gets very few variables while parent process (shell) has access to so many environment variables

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a permissions issue. Linux is very context aware when it comes to environment variables, so if the context where the variables are created is different from the one attempting to retrieve them... In your example, are the EV being created from the same shell where the app is being launched?

Comment: Yes EV created using the same shell from which dotnet process is launched.

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case, its worth reading [the docs for the method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariables?view=netcore-2.0). When we do, we see this excerpt:

> On non-Windows systems, the GetEnvironmentVariables method retrieves the name and value of all environment variables that are inherited from the parent process that launched the dotnet process or that are defined within the scope of the dotnet process itself. Once the dotnet process ends, these latter environment variables cease to exist.
>
> **.NET running on Unix-based systems does not support per-machine or per-user environment variables.**

*(emphasis mine)*

Comment: Good catch, so you would definitely need to have the parent process create the EVs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using version of this method, which supports target as the second argument. It can be, that these environment variables are not visible to process target.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to set environment variables in the same thread where .NET Core is running and use SetEnvironmentVariable.

[image]

In the image, if you set ENV_PATH_CONFIG in the terminal, when you run your code, it's not possible to get ENV_PATH_CONFIG. However, if you set it before retrieving it, you can view the value.

Is more easy if you set launchSettings.json file.